# Is it possible to automate file moving and naming via Windows CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm looking for a way to, on boot, move everything on my desktop to Users/[My User]/Archive/[TODAYSDATE]/. Is this possible to do in Windows with a BAT-script? I've done a similar thing on Linux and a friend helped me with Cron jobs.

How would a script like that be written, and how would it be automated? Scheduled task?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scheduled tasks.
In Windows xp you can find it in control panel.

In latest versions it is in control panel > administrative tools.

I think the script would look like this

```
move /Y path\of\origin\* path\of\destination
```

Comment: This method won't copy files that are in sub-directories within the given folder. For that you need robocopy.

Comment: Oh I didn't heared about it . Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

For the batch file, it can be as simple as:

```
robocopy your_folder_path your_destination_path /SEC /MIR /V /TS
del your_folder_path\*
```

And then as suggested prior, just set a scheduled task in Windows. How you set it up will depend on which version of Windows you're running.

Comment: See [Wikipedia: robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) -- it comes standard with Vista/7/Server 2008 and is available as part of a Resource Kit for other versions.